# Найти и вывести максимальный элемент из коллекции MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, база-данных, mongodb

```
[
 {
   _id: ObjectId("63ce4976d52b8e0552f39645"),
   name: 'Спартак',
   competition: {
     date: '15.01.2023',
     matches: [
       {
         number: 1,
         name: 'Спартак-Динамо',
         players: [
           { fio: 'Потапов К.С.', goalcount: 0 },
           { fio: 'Бочаров М.П.', goalcount: 1 },
           { fio: 'Петров А.И.', goalcount: 0 },
           { fio: 'Сергеев К.О.', goalcount: 2 },
           { fio: 'Любимов И.А.', goalcount: 0 }
         ]
       },
       {
         number: 2,
         name: 'Спартак-Урал',
         players: [
           { fio: 'Потапов К.С.', goalcount: 1 },
           { fio: 'Бочаров М.П.', goalcount: 0 },
           { fio: 'Петров А.И.', goalcount: 1 },
           { fio: 'Сергеев К.О.', goalcount: 0 },
           { fio: 'Ковалёв М.А.', goalcount: 2 }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 },
 {
   _id: ObjectId("63ce4976d52b8e0552f39646"),
   name: 'Рубин',
   competition: {
     date: '10.01.2023',
     matches: [
       {
         number: 1,
         name: 'Рубин-Ростов',
         players: [
           { fio: 'Бородаев И.С.', goalcount: 0 },
           { fio: 'Шевчук М.А.', goalcount: 3 },
           { fio: 'Бродский К.И.', goalcount: 0 },
           { fio: 'Потапов К.И.', goalcount: 0 },
           { fio: 'Михайлов Г.А.', goalcount: 1 }
         ]
       },
       {
         number: 2,
         name: 'Рубин-Краснодар',
         players: [
           { fio: 'Бородаев И.С.', goalcount: 0 },
           { fio: 'Шевчук М.А.', goalcount: 1 },
           { fio: 'Громилов А.П.', goalcount: 4 },
           { fio: 'Потапов К.И.', goalcount: 0 },
           { fio: 'Михайлов Г.А', goalcount: 0 }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }
]
```

Как мне вывести футболиста, забившего больше всего голов(goalcount)?

Comment: Поскольку у тебя есть Нода, значит можно подключить любой, удобный тебе, модуль для работы с Монго. Далее пройтись по документам и сделать новый массив с элементами типа `{fio, sum}`. По окончании прохода найти максимальный из нового массива. Или ты хочешь воспользоваться агрегацией и типа одним запросом все узнать?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете вывести следующим образом

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo.collection("collection").aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$competition.matches.players"},
    {$sort: {"competition.matches.players.goalcount": -1}},
    {$limit:1},
    {$project: {fio: "$competition.matches.players.fio", goalcount: "$competition.matches.players.goalcount"}}
  ]).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Еще можете использовать код агрегации MongoDB, чтобы найти максимальное количество голов и соответствующего игрока. Это сделает следующий код:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
       {$unwind:"$competition.matches.players"},
       {$sort: {"competition.matches.players.goalcount": -1}},
       {$limit:1},
       {$project: {fio: "$competition.matches.players.fio", goalcount: 
       "$competition.matches.players.goalcount"}}
])
```

Сначала раскручивает массив «игроков», чтобы каждый игрок находился в отдельном документе. Затем сортируется документы по количеству голов в порядке убывания, ограничивает результат первым документом и проецирует окончательный вывод так, чтобы он включал только поля fio и число голов. Результатом станет игрок с наибольшим количеством голов.
Затем вы можете использовать драйвер MongoDB для JavaScript, чтобы запросить вашу коллекцию MongoDB и выполнить этот конвейер, чтобы найти игрока с наибольшим количеством голов.
Вы также можете изменить поля на этапе проекта в соответствии с вашими требованиями.